# How can I move keyframes further apart in ToonBoom?

Tags: animation, tools

I've created an animation entirely out of screen capture fragments and keyframes, and I haven't allowed enough time for one portion.  I'd like to simply stretch out the time between two keyframes, pushing all other keyframes and exposures out to the right, but I can't see how to do it.

Here's a screenshot that shows my situation:

[image: pictorial explanation]

How do I do this?

Comment: Only people with experience with Toon Boom will be able to help you. You might have more luck if they have a support forum.

Comment: Yeah, I posted there, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I did eventually manage to figure this out.  It turns out that if you SELECT all the stuff you want to move, you can just drag it all, and it'll move keyframes and everything.  The keyframes will move along with the frame sequences that contain them, if those sequences are selected (turn them purple, if I remember right).